# InforPath forms and one click open

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I am by no means a SP expert!  However, I have managed to figure out and create an InfoPath form and have published it to a site I own.  It works fine, but it is a 2 step process.  When I published the form and named it (Change Request Form), a link was created on my home page on the left nav under Recent called Change Request form.  When I click on it I am taken to a new page, where I then have to click on "new" in order to actually open the form and enter data.  What I want to do is have a link that when clicked actually opens the form (as if "new" was already selected) ready to accept data. Screen shots below show where the nav link is and the page you are taken to when you click, and then the form once you click New.

Any help appreciated - I've been searching and asking questions all over and SP is not the easiest or intuitive app to use and I haven't come across anything that makes sense or looks easy enough for me to do.
Thanks
Leslie

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the "recent" menu option you see is created each time you create a new library, 
that links take you to the view of all the items of the library, probably information you don't want to show to all the users.

i recommend you to remove it and don't depend on it because it will host up to 5 items, after the 6th item is added, the 1st will be pushed out from the menu. 
they also disappear after 2 weeks.

the next step is to follow A.Saéed steps, but i would also recommend to fix the url to have somethinkg like this:

"sharepoint.com/site/library/newifs.aspx"

everything after the newifs.aspx is almost uselss, except for the "source" parameter

ADVANCED: you can redirect the user to another sharepoint page when they submit or cancel

you can do this by adding the source parameter to the url 
"?source=sharepoint.com/site/sitepages/home.aspx"

so you'll end up with something like this : 
"sharepoint.com/site/site/library/newifs.aspx?source=sharepoint.com/site/sitepages/home.aspx

Comment: I tried A.Saeed's steps below and get an error, so need to understand your suggestion to "fix" the URL.  Can you further explain?  As I said, not an expert on SP at all, this is all new to me :-( so hope I don't sound too dense!  Also rather than have it listed under recent, how could I add it to the page as a permanent link?

Answer (score 0):

Me too...from my home page navigation, using the Publishing Site template, on SPO, I could not convince SharePoint to open up the InfoPath form directly.  Copying the URL from the New Item button would first take me to the view, if I click the link again it worked.  Now, the home page appears to be classic, and my view is using the modern experience.  Clicking the InfoPath form first opens the view in modern.

What worked for me is to open the list in classic view, copy the New Item URL which uses listform.aspx instead of newifs.aspx - the link works, opening up InfoPath directly using newifs.aspx.  Repeated twice on two troublemaker links, so perhaps this will do it.

Comment: Welcome to SE:SharePoint, and thanks for contributing! Feel free to have a look around, and check out the Help Center for advice on what makes a good question/answer on our site: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score -1):

1. open the new form
2. copy url from the brower
3. navigate to home page
4. click on the edit links as in the below image
5. add new link for the copied URL (as on the below screen)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I tried this, I opened the form, copied the URL from the browser, cliced on Edit Links, pasted it in and saved but then get this error:  Edit LinksThis animation indicates the operation is in progress. Click to remove this animated image.
 There was a problem. Some of your changes may have been saved. Cannot open "/teams/FieldEnablementEvents/team-only/_layouts/15/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=https://hpe.sharepoint.com/teams/FieldEnablementEvents/team-only/Change%20Request%20form/Forms/template.xsn&Sav": no such file or folder.

Comment: @LeslieScouras i added a new image in my answer to explain more how to add a new link, to make it easier for you take the whole URL starting from  /teams/FieldEnablementEvents/ to the end don't remove anything else

Comment: Thanks A.Saeed, I didn't have a problem there but rather when I pasted in the URL from the open forms page (copied URL from the browser bar) and tried to save it I got the error below.  When I clicked on "Try the Link" it worked fine, but it won't save it w/o giving the error.  So was hoping to better understand Erin's post on how to modify the URL.  Maybe by doing that it would work, but I don't understand how to do that piece.

Comment: Just an FYI - I finally figured out how to make this work.  I needed to ADD a new link not edit the one that was there.  Thanks for all the help though!

Comment: @LeslieScouras maybe i wasn't clear enough, but glad you figured it out :)